# Extract first value os the pair list

Tags: scheme

I'm new in scheme programming and I just want to extract the  Items of the pair List. Example my variable

```
val==> ((a . 1) (b . 0.026279533) (c . 0.026616231) (d . 0.0060348272) (e . 0.00070986058) (f . 0.050281039) (g . 0.12546714) (h . 0.00014385414))
```

And I want to print into two list type:

```
a b c d e f g h

1 0.026279533 0.026616231 0.0060348272 0.00070986058 0.050281039 0.12546714 0.00014385414
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(display (map car val))
(newline)
(display (map cdr val))
(newline)
```